# Additional parameters to callback function

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I'm using `getCurrentPosition` from the HTML5 geolocation functions but need to pass more than just the `position` parameter to the sucess callback function. (the `getCurrentPosition` callback is only supplied with the `position` parameter by default)

How can I do this?

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(doOnSuccess, true);

function doOnSuccess(position, switchFlag) {
    // process the position based on the value of switchFlag
}
```

My actual code is a lot more complex than this and the `doOnSuccess` function is re-used a number of times elsewhere so using anonymous function is not really an option.

Comment: If you leave out `switchFlag` from `function doOnSuccess..`, you already have access to the `var switchFlag` as is... Does this not work for you either?

Comment: It's actually my example code that's causing confusion here.. the mySwitchFlag variable doesn't actually exist in my code, though creating it as per your comment would be one solution. I've actually worked out what I was trying to acheive anyway - use an anonymous function to call the doOnSuccess function with the required additional argument e.g. `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function() {doOnSuccess(position,true);});`

Comment: I've now corrected the code in the OP to make it clearer what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment above, the clue to the answer was actually in the question - you DO use an anonymous function and then use that to call the correct function with all the required parameters.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function() {
    doOnSuccess(position,true);
});

function doOnSuccess(position, switchFlag) {
    // process the position based on the value of switchFlag
}
```